# vscode custom key binding length issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am binding custom keys with keybindings.json file like below,

```
 {
    "key": "s a",
    "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
    "when": "vim.mode == 'Normal'"
}, {
    "key": "q u",
    "command": "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
    "when": "vim.mode == 'Normal'"
}
```

It seems that vscode supports only custom keys length to 2.

Is there any way to binding keys (length) more than that?

for example

```
 {
    "key": "s a v e",
    "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
    "when": "vim.mode == 'Normal'"
}, {
    "key": "q u i t",
    "command": "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
    "when": "vim.mode == 'Normal'"
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but could not find the fix to this issue despite my researches, curious about this one...

Meanwhile, I use a workaround with betterTouchTool for Mac Os and it does the job perfectly (you can assign key sequences per app or globally). For instance I set the key sequence `pry` to be replaced by `binding.pry` on the fly (with keybindings.json it was triggered too early, as soon as I hit the 'r'), but you can as well trigger any other action. 
I guess it's not the only app allowing this kind of customisation but I use this one a lot and didn't search any further.

Hope this helps!